# How to retrieve information from database based on some specific condition and load them into html table using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a search page with two fields: state and city (both are using html select tag), and I am using jQuery to validate those two fields.

I am using jQuery's `$.post()` to retrieve data from database as like as follow:

```
$.post('database.php',
    {
        state   :   $( '#state' ).val(),
        city    :   $( '#city' ).val()
    },

    function(response)
    {
        alert(response);
    }
);
```

and the database query used in **database.php** is:

```
select * from my_tbl where tb_state = '$state' and tb_city = '$city';
```

So far everything is ok and the result is correctly shown by `$.post()` **response**, but I want to retreive those information in PHP, instead of jQuery.

So my question is:
Is it possible to convert `$.post()` response into PHP or retrieve those response in PHP? If yes then how can I do that? If no than how can I retrieve database values into html table based on the above database query using PHP without refreshing the same page or loading new page?

Comment: you want to add the response to your html?? id so use `.html()`

Comment: your question is not very clear please explain

Comment: do you want response in html table format ?

Answer (score 3):

Modify your function as follows

```
$.post( "database.php", { state: $( '#state' ).val(), city: $( '#state' ).val() })
  .done(function( data ) {
     $('#id_of the element to insert data').html(data );
  });
```

**UPDATE**

`$.post()` is a `jquery` method to retrieve data asynchronously. If you want to change the data retrieval to PHP, simply post these data using a form or pass this as `query string`. On the receiving PHP end accept these parameters using `$_POST` /  `$_GET` method, trigger a database query and send back to your page.

Answer (score 0):

You have done correctly but only missing the last step.

To add your response to your view use `.html()` or `.append()`

```
$.post('database.php',
  {
       state   :   $( '#state' ).val(),
       city    :   $( '#city' ).val()
  },
  function(response)
  {
       $("your class or id selector").html(response);// this line will add the response to your html view.If any content is there in the selector, it will overwrite.

       or you can use `.append()`

       $("your class or id selector").append(response);//as name suggests, it will append the response
  }
);
```

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp) ans [this](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for `.html()` ans see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp) for `.append()`. For other options, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xtb51wed/)